# Change KDE Plasma default wallpaper

Tags: kubuntu, kde, desktop-background, plasma

So I was working on my KDE Plasma desktop with a nice wallpaper I had chosen. However, when I started, I started using the "activities" feature and started regularly adding and removing activities I was faced with a problem: the new activities take the default Kubuntu wallpaper (at the time of writing this was Next) instead of my set wallpaper. I tried to follow the answer over [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/588590/how-to-change-default-wallpaper-in-kde), but it didn't work, the background of new activities remained the same. In the process of modifying that file, I noticed something strange though: the wallpaper set there does not match the actual default wallpaper. Here is the file:

```
...
[Wallpaper]
defaultWallpaperTheme=Elarun # The actual default wallpaper is Next!
defaultFileSuffix=.png
defaultWidth=2560
defaultHeight=1600
```

I checked whether the Elarun theme (maybe) contains the Next wallpaper, and it doesn't

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT:
The same happens when I connect an external screen and "extend" to it: it gets the default wallpaper.

Comment: Which version of Kubuntu are you on? The link you mentioned is for Kubuntu 14.04.

Comment: @DKBose, I am on Kubuntu 19.04. The link I mentioned is indeed for Kubuntu 14.04, I could not find any others that addressed my problem...

Comment: I don't use wallpapers or activities. If you don't get help here, try asking at [Kubuntu Forums](https://www.kubuntuforums.net), or [KDE Community Forums](https://forum.kde.org), or [reddit/kde](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/) or [reddit/kubuntu](https://www.reddit.com/r/Kubuntu/).

Comment: @DKBose, alright, thanks for your time! At least I have useful links to help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, found an answer myself somehow. Apparently, new versions of KDE Plasma use another file than mentioned in the older answer. The new file is located at `/usr/share/plasma/desktoptheme/(themename)/metadata.desktop` and works pretty much the same way with the only difference that it is theme-specific.

The steps I suggest are:

1. Copy the `desktoptheme` you are currently using to a folder with a custom name. (For example, copy Breeze `/usr/share/plasma/desktoptheme/breeze` to `/usr/share/plasma/desktoptheme/canobreeze` or so)
2. Edit the `metadata.desktop`'s `defaultWallpaperTheme` to the wallpaper you prefer.
3. (Optional, but handy) Edit the `metadata.desktop`'s name to something you like. This is to differentiate between your theme and the original one.
4. Set the `defaultWidth` and `defaultHeight`. You can find the available sizes at `/usr/share/wallpapers/(wallpapername)/contents/images`. Please note: not all wallpapers shipped with plasma have the same sizes. For example: the Next wallpaper has a lot of sizes, while Canopee only has one. IF THE SIZE IS NOT SET CORRECTLY THE WALLPAPER WON'T WORK!!!
5. Look in the System Settings for 'Workspace Theme' (or in plasma search 'Plasma Theme').
6. Set the theme to your own, modified version (it has the name specified in the `metadata.desktop` file)
7. And there it is: when you create a new activity or connect a new screen, you will get your custom wallpaper.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the accepted answer, but if you have any other way to solve this problem, please share it and maybe I'll mark _that_ as the right answer.

Comment: I with there was a way to edit only files within your homedir.